# Check if a number is an integer or non-integer rational

Tags: clojure

How can I test a number and see if it is an integer and not a non-integer rational number?

**spoiler warning** Taken from a 4clojure.com problem.

### Context

Consider this function:

```
(defn qux [n i]
  (reduce + (range 1 (/ n i))))
```

The last element in the range is the number of positive integers that are less than `n` and divisible by i.

```
user> (qux 10 3) ; 3, 6, & 9 are divisible by 3, sum(1, 2, 3) = 6
6
user> (qux 10 5) ; 5 is divisible by 5, sum(1) = 1
1
```

I would like to generate the sum, without generating the range. `sum(1..N) = N(N + 1)/2` to the rescue. 
The problem is that `N` is the greatest integer that is strictly less than `n / i`. My incorrect attempt was:

```
(defn how-many [n i] 
  (int (/ n i)))
(defn sum-1-to-N [n]
  (/ (* n (+ n 1)) 2))
(defn qux-prime [n i]
  (sum-1-to-N (how-many n i)))

user> (qux-prime 10 5)
3
```

So I would like to test the result of `(/ n i)` and subtract one if it is an integer, otherwise truncate using `int`. (Not using `floor` because I don't want to import the whole numeric tower, because not sure how to even do that on 4clojure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [built-in `integer?` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/integer_q):

```
=> (integer? (/ 10 5)) ; true
```

Here is a complete example:

```clj
(defn qux-prime [n i]
  (let [r (/ n i)
        n (if (integer? r) (dec r) (int r))]
    (/ (* n (+ n 1)) 2)))
```

Comment: Nice, handles the different classes that hold different size integers. I didn't look far enough, stopping after checking for `int?`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this situation in another context, and found that

```
(if (== (int n) n) ; test to see if n is an integer - done this way (instead
   (do-if-true)    ;   of integer?) so that float integers will be detected 
   (do-if-false))  ;   correctly
```

worked well.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: For floating integers, wouldn't you need `(== (int n) n)`? Because ints and floats are not `=`?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - that's what I get for typing from memory instead of copying. Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several core functions that work directly with integers, and since your problem deals with these, it is maybe a little better than relying on coercion with `int` function :

- [quot](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quot)
- [mod](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mod)
- [rem](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rem)

which gives for `qux` :

```
(defn qux2 [n i]
  (let [p (quot n i)
        q (if (zero? (rem n i)) (dec p) p)]
    (quot (* q (inc q)) 2)))
```

I benched it with [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) :

```
(require '[criterium.core :as c])
(let [p (rand-int 1000000)
      q (rand-int 10000)
      N 1000]
  (println "=========" p q)
  (c/quick-bench (dotimes [_ N] (qux p q)))
  (c/quick-bench (dotimes [_ N] (qux2 p q)))
  (c/quick-bench (dotimes [_ N] (qux-prime p q))))
```

On my mbp :

```
========= 364347 9361
...
             Execution time mean : 6.111392 ms [=> with reduce] 
...
             Execution time mean : 69.042004 µs [=> with quot, rem]
...
             Execution time mean : 294.989561 µs [=> with int, integer?]
...
```

It looks like when dealing with integer specific functions, you have a significant performance gain.